# Find the creator of a task

Tags: linux-kernel, process-management

I would like to find the creator task of an arbitrary task in the Linux kernel. However, I am not sure, if there is a way to do this in general.

Normally, you can find the creator of a task via the `real_parent` member in its `struct task_struct`. My problem lies in the kernel's handling of thread groups.

Assume a process in user mode (task A in the kernel) creates a thread (task B in the kernel). To do this, the `clone` syscall is made with the `CLONE_THREAD` flag. The kernel then copies task A to create task B and performs thread-specific initialization. Part of this is, that the `real_parent` of B is set to the `real_parent` of A ([see code in kernel/fork.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/fork.c#L1478)).

So, the parent relation is between thread groups (i.e., processes in user mode), not between tasks. It seems that tasks in a thread group are viewed as siblings with no hierarchy between them.

This makes it non-obvious to me how to find out which task a given task was created by. I inspected the forking code and searched through the members of `struct task_struct` but found nothing. Is there even a way to identify the creator of a task?